# how to change negative number's color in output in Rstudio?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I am new in R and recently came across a video where **negative numbers color in console was changed to red** which is something I am trying to recreate for my `Rstudio` outputs.

[image]

from one of the SO post I tried below code but that didn't help.

```
[data-negative] {
  color: red;
}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>555</td>
    <td data-negative>-555</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Appreciate if someone could help me with this for both `Rstudio output` and `rmarkdown knitted` documents.

Comment: The output in your screenshot is a `tibble`, which should automatically color negative values red if you have the correct version of the package `dplyr` (I think is the correct package) and RStudio. Example: `data.frame(plus = c(1,2), minus = c(-1, -2)) %>% dplyr::as_tibble()`. WIth regards to red negative values in knitted documents, you should ask a separate question. You can also easily figure this out by trying a google search.

Comment: thanks @henrik_ibsen, it worked as you said.